# OpenVPN Unrecognized option or missing or extra parameter(s) in client.ovpn:126: < (2.4.0)

Tags: openvpn, raspbian

I`ve got problem with OpenVPN on raspberry. When I try to connect using Windows : 
Options error: Unrecognized option or missing or extra parameter(s) in client.ovpn:126: < (2.4.0)

Here is my client config :

```
client

dev tun


proto udp

remote x.x.x.x 1194


resolv-retry infinite

nobind

user nobody
group nogroup

persist-key
persist-tun

;ca ca.crt
;cert client.crt
;key client.key

ns-cert-type server

cipher AES-128-CBC
auth SHA256

comp-lzo

key-direction 1

verb 3
```

Comment: I think that some options are missing in your OpenVPN client configuration. Can you please upload your full client configuration ?

Comment: Why have you commented out the `ca`, `cert` and `key` options?